# Facebook Login OAuth URL leading to blank page with a 500 error

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-authentication

I'm making an app that only I will use. Because of this, I'm able to use the extended permissions without needing Facebook to approve the app as my account is also the developer account.

Anyway, I'm manually building a login flow. I have been using this URL to authenticate the app:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://delta.identity-demo.com:8443/exit102em/aa/facebook&scope=basic_info,email,user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_photos,user_questions,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_subscriptions,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,read_mailbox&state=12

I have two app IDs. One from a couple of months ago, and one I made last week. The older app ID works with this URL. However, the newer app ID does not and I end up with a blank page with a 500 response.

The two app IDs are as follows:

Old ID - 386918378110985

New ID - 145019279001886

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. The extensive scope and state variable are necessary for my uses. I cannot remove them.

Comment: `basic_info` permission does not exist any more. Once I remove that from the URL, it shows the first panel of the login dialog as expected.

Comment: Thank you, this was a massive help. That was the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`basic_info` permission does not exist any more. Once I remove that from the URL, it shows the first panel of the login dialog as expected.

(`basic_info` has been replaced with `public_profile` permission – but as the docs say, if you are doing login from the web, it is set as default already and you do not have to ask for it specifically via `scope`.)